# How to use Memory<T> on large arrays (unlike arrays it doesn't have a LongLength property)

Tags: c#, arrays, memory, .net-core, .net-standard-2.0

Does it support > 32 bit indices and if so what's the way to get it's length properly? Otherwise is there any workaround? The whole point of high performance memory API in my use case is for large chunks of data, way beyond 32 bit length arrays.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26603

Comment: @mjwills Everything in there is from 2018, and none of the workarounds are of use to me, i'm just wondering if there's a way to get 64 bit / if there will be a way to get 64 bit Memory<T> with LongLength just like we've had with list. The linked thread seems to aknowledge the issue but goes nowhere in the end